# New sentence from doc2vec model trained with wikicorpus

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I'm training a Doc2Vec model from the french wikipedia.

My code is based on this notebook :
https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-wikipedia.ipynb

It's actually in the training phase, but, I don't know how to vectorize new sentences after that.

Should I just use : model.infer_vector["Example sentence here"] ?
But in this case, how to make the same processing than the Wikicorpus method does ? (This is not explained here : https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/wikicorpus.html)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but `infer_vector()` is a method to be called with arguments, rather than an object offering `[]`-indexing. And, it requires a list-of-word-tokens, not a raw string. So with your tiny example sentence, a better call would be:

```
model.infer_vector(['Example', 'sentence', 'here'])
```

However, you do want to be sure to preprocess & tokenize your later sentences the same way as was done with the training data - so that capitalization, punctuation, etc is treated the same way. (Otherwise, it's more likely many of the tokens you try to infer-from won't have exact equivalents in the model, and thus be ignored.)

You can review the source for what gensim's `WikiCorpus` does at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/f97d0e793faa57877a2bbedc15c287835463eaa9/gensim/corpora/wikicorpus.py#L340

Specifically, you could reuse the `gensim.utils.tokenize()` function on plain-text to match its tokenization. (If you needed to do the full "wiki-text" preprocessing, you'd want to match or re-use the other methods in that file).